# React Native + react-native-router-flux: What does <Scene key='modal' component={Modal}/> do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am new to react-native-router-flux and taking a look at the example. I checked the docs but I still can't seem to figure out what `<Scene key='modal' component={Modal}/>`. So what is its usage?

Here is the exact line: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/Example/Example.js#L95-Lundefined

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`<Scene key='modal' component={Modal}/>` sets up the app so that the modal can appear on top of EVERYTHING else. It's not the modal itself, just the line used to prep the app that it 'could' load something else over the top of it all...like z-index or the top most layer being initialized. Does that help?

Reference: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#modals-modal-or-scene-modal

From the code example below, you can see that the 'root' (one level below your modal line) is on the same level as the 'actual' modal:

```
import StatusModal from './components/StatusModal'

<Router>
  <Scene key="modal" component={Modal} >
    <Scene key="root">
      <Scene key="screen1" initial={true} component={Screen1} />
      <Scene key="screen2" component={Screen2} />
    </Scene>
    <Scene key="statusModal" component={StatusModal} />
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

If you don't have a modal, you don't need that line. It's just in the react native router flux examples because there is a modal demo'd in there.

Comment: The reference @jakeatwork linked has been moved to https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#modals-modal-or-scene-modal after version 4 was released.